# Isnt there spring data equivalant APIs for Quarkus to perform aggregate operations on MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb-query, quarkus, quarkus-panache, quarkus-rest-client

I am looking for equivalant of elegant usage of APIs (spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb) to perform aggregates on MongoDB collections for:

Defining custom repository to implement MatchOperation, GroupOperation, ProjectionOperation and use an Aggregation to define strategy (liken mentioned below)

```
public List<WarehouseSummary> aggregate(float minPrice, float maxPrice) {
    MatchOperation matchOperation = getMatchOperation(minPrice, maxPrice);
    GroupOperation groupOperation = getGroupOperation();
    ProjectionOperation projectionOperation = getProjectOperation();
     
    return mongoTemplate.aggregate(Aggregation.newAggregation(
        matchOperation,
        groupOperation,
        projectionOperation
    ), Product.class, WarehouseSummary.class).getMappedResults();
}
```

could not find any of this feature on publicly available platform